# Send form with files using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload, form-data

```
$('#add-article').submit(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($(this));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/add-article',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        //processData: false,
        //contentType: false,
        error: function(data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            $.each(errors, function(k, v) {
                $('#' + k).addClass('has-error').append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + v[0] + '</strong></span>');
            });
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.replace(data.url);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

When I comment out `porcessData: false`, the form did get submitted, but through standard form submit not Ajax, and gave me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

If I add these two lines in, ajax will submit an empty form.

My form:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('post_add_article') }}" id="add-article" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="16" name="body"></textarea>

                        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems solved by replacing `var formData = new FormData($(this));` with `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);`